# Compress the video quality and upload to firebase could not compress the size of the mp4 video

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

What we are trying to do in our application is to record a video and upload it to firebase but we wanna reduce the size of the video before uploading what I have tried is setting the intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,0.9);
but the moment we set the quality to 0.9 the video gets compressed but there s no voice to the video and it gets saved in 3gp
AND when we icrease the quality to 1
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
the video of 1min goes upto 200mb in size

```
enter code 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Uri videouri;
Button button;
private StorageReference videoRef;
private DatabaseReference ref;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorde=new MediaRecorder();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    videoRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("videos");
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("videos");
    button=findViewById(R.id.button3);
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
 StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

                videoRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("videos");
                ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("videos");
                String abc=String.valueOf(videouri);
          Log.i("info", "onClick: "+abc);
                String filename=abc.replace("content://media/external/video/media/","");
          Log.i("info", "onClick: "+filename);
                videoRef = storageRef.child("/videos/"  + filename);




          upload();
      }
  });
   }
   private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}

  public void upload() {
    if (videouri != null) {
//            final DatabaseReference ac= ref.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
 //                  + "." + getFileExtension(videouri));
        final UploadTask uploadTask = videoRef.putFile(videouri);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success fully uploaded"oast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                updateProgress(taskSnapshot);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }

    public void updateProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

    long fileSize = taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

    long UploadBytes = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
    long progress = (100 * UploadBytes) / fileSize;
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbar);
    progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);


}

    public void record(View view) {

    //        mediaRecorde.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
     //        mediaRecorde.setVideoEncodingBitRate(690000);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,0.9);
    //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT,21966080L);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,60);
     //        MediaRecorder mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
      //        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);



    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

  }




protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
videouri=data.getData();

  if(resultCode==1){
Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n"+videouri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


 }else if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
Toast.makeText(this, "RECORDING CANCELLED.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
//  Toast.makeText(this, "failed to record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n"+videouri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}

}
```

Comment: Is android supposed to have the functionality you want? Compressing video to high bitrates is rumoured to be expensive in terms of CPU and battery power, so it might be that they picked a couple of settings that are tolerably battery-friendly. Do you know for a fact that Android is supposed to do what you want?